# Average of an arbitrary amount of numbers

Tags: c, average

I'm currently trying to create a C program for a class assignment that takes the average of an arbitrary amount of test scores. However, I've run into some problems.

My professor has provided an outline to help get started. I also can only add code where indicated, so no extra variables and such.

This is what I have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void calculateAverage()
{
    int grade, count, sum;
    double average;

/*     add code to input grades, calculate average, and print it */
/* --> between here */

printf("Enter the amount of test scores.\n");
scanf("%d", &count);

grade = 0;
sum = 0;

while (grade != -1 && grade <= 100 && grade >= 0)
{
    printf("Enter the grade. Enter -1 when you are done entering grades.\n");
    scanf("%d", &grade);

    if (grade != -1 && grade <= 100 && grade >= 0)
    {           
        sum = sum + grade;      
    }

    else
    {
        average = (sum / count);

        printf("average is %.2lf \n", &average);
    }

}
/* --> and here */
}

int main(void)
{
    while (1)
        calculateAverage();
return 0;
}
```

So the problem I've ran into is that with what I have so far, the average will always be calculated as 0. Why exactly is this happening, and how would I fix it so it gives me the correct average?

**UPDATE**
So I tried casting the average to double so I can avoid a type mismatch, which did get rid of my compiler warnings but the average is still coming out to 0 for all inputed values.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void calculateAverage()
{
    int grade, count, sum;
    double average;

/*     add code to input grades, calculate average, and print it */
/* --> between here */

printf("Enter the amount of test scores.\n");
scanf("%d", &count);

grade = 0;
sum = 0;

while (grade != -1 && grade <= 100 && grade >= 0)
{
    printf("Enter the grade. Enter -1 when you are done entering grades.\n");
    scanf("%d", &grade);

    if (grade != -1 && grade <= 100 && grade >= 0)
    {           
        sum = sum + grade;      
    }

    else
    {

        average = (double)(sum / count);

        printf("average is %.2f \n", &average);
    }

}
/* --> and here */
}

int main(void)
{
    while (1)
        calculateAverage();

return 0;
}
```

Comment: There is nothing in this program that stops the user from saying they will enter 3 grades, and then actually entering 1000000.  Why not count as you go?  Also, there's no need to test explicitly for `-1`, since that's already outside your 0-100 range test.  Unless you want to do something special with it.

Comment: Turn on your compiler warnings (`-Wall -Wextra` if using gcc or clang). You should be getting one about your use of printf.

Comment: I used -1 because my professor wanted us to use that to terminate each group of grades.

Comment: The average should only be printed once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

void calculateAverage()
{
    int grade, count, sum;
    double average;

/*     add code to input grades, calculate average, and print it */
/* --> between here */

printf("Enter the amount of test scores.\n");
scanf("%d", &count);

grade = 0;
sum = 0;

while (grade != -1 && grade <= 100 && grade >= 0)
{
    printf("Enter the grade. Enter -1 when you are done entering grades.\n");
    scanf("%d", &grade);

    if (grade != -1 && grade <= 100 && grade >= 0)
    {           
        sum = sum + grade;      
    }

    else
    {

        average = (double)(sum / count);

        printf("average is %.2lf \n", average);  #  <---- Please fix this!
    }

}
/* --> and here */
}

int main(void)
{
    while (1)
        calculateAverage();

return 0;
}
```

There are a few problems in your code:

1. One is you are printing the address of average using `&` operator.
2. Another thing you can change is to use the `correct format specifier` when printing double.

Comment: What do you consider is wrong with the format used to print the `double` value?

Comment: We use %lf to print the double values.

Comment: Ah, that printf statement did seem to be what was making average 0 all the time. Thank you for the feedback!

Comment: @Tareun, please upvote and accept the answer if it helped.

Comment: You can use `%lf` to print `double` values as long as the library conforms to C99 or later, but in C90 only `%f` is valid, and it continues to be valid in later standards.  Granted, using the newer notation is consistent with the format used in `scanf()`; that was a major reason for adding the functionality.  But because all `float` values are always promoted to `double` before being passed to `printf()`, there never has been a way to print a `float`.  The notation has always printed `double` values.